# Vue does not Render Template with Webpack, Compaining about Runtime Only Build

Tags: vue.js, webpack

First, let me tell that my aim is to integrate Vue to my existing codebase. I have also found Webpack to be very useful and set it up to my needs. Not that I am very competent about webpack but get the basic idea and did it somehow.

In order to use Vue in an existing project, I chose to integrate it with plain Javascript, not compiling `.vue` files due to complexity, my project's requirements and also time. So, in my codebase, somewhere, I'd like to initialize a `Vue` instance targeting a DOM element and hardcode the template in my HTML. Let me show it in code to make it more clear. Below is a part of my HTML:

```html
<div id="entry-component">
  <p>Hello {{ message }}!</p>
</div>

<!-- I use Django and `verbatim` here to escape Django templating inside. -->
<!-- Also, consider `component` here as a part of HTML page, not in sense of Vue.
     A page can have multiple `whatever-component` and initialize multiple `Vue` instances. -->
```

And also my Javascript files:

```js
// app.js
// entry point for webpack

// some imports here...
import 'vue'
// I do this because I hardcoded my template (`message` variable) inside
// my HTML and only want runtime Vue.
import './components/entry.js'
// this contains my `Vue` instance

////////////////////////

// ./components/entry.js

import Vue from 'vue'
// otherwise it throws error complaining it cannot resolve what `Vue` is

const entryComponent = new Vue({
  el: "#entry-component",
  data: {message: "world"}
})
```

So, this compiles successfully. However, I fire up my dev server, go to related page containing this component and something *odd* happens.

Firstly, it does not even render `Hello` part. This actually means Vue successfully is loaded and mounted on the target DOM element. This is the part I do not get. I've already told "Replace `{{message}}` with `message`. Why does it not render it and completely wipes out the content of `#entry-component`?

Thanks in advance.

## Troubleshooting

### Runtime Vue Warning (?)

The other thing I think that might be relevant is the warning the browser throws in dev console:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.
```

This is probably because I did `import 'vue'` in my `app.js`. I exactly want runtime only Vue. I don't know if this causes for template hardcoded in HTML to not render. This seems like an error and don't know if it stops execution of the client-side Javascript.

### Explicitly Importing Dist Build of Vue

The error above has given me some clues and wanted to try to *explicitly* import distribution builds of vue. I've imported below but no luck:

```js
// app.js
// instead of > import 'vue'
import 'vue/dist/vue.js'  // still same error
import 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'  // nope
import 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'  // no
```

I've also read `README.md` in `dist` folder. It says `vue.js` has *all*, includes compiler but still no luck.

---

## Environment

- I don't know if it is relevant but I use Django and I'm double sure I use `verbatim` to escape Django templating.
- Vue ^2.6.10
- Webpack ^4.41.2
- Webpack CLI ^3.3.10
- NPM 6.12.1
- Node 12.13.0

Comment: You must compile Vue templates though. The `{{ }}` syntax is not something that is understood by the Vue runtime, those are compiled into function calls by the Vue template compiler.

Comment: @RossAllen | So I install it with NPM and import it instead of vue (or before/after?)? Is `vue-template-compiler` the correct package name?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem myself and would like to share the answer for Googlers.

So, it appears to be that I've actually imported two different `Vue` builds. One is in `app.js` and the other is in the related component file.

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
```

However, that `Vue` class actually builds up a bundle in which template compiler does not exist. So, you need to do two things:

1. First, you need to delete the import on your entry file, in this case, `app.js`.
2. Then you need to specify where you get your `Vue` class in your related file, in this case, the build including template compiler. See below:

```js
// entry.js
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
// this contains the template compiler
```

This solved my problem.